# CQRS - execute two handlers

Tags: architecture, cqrs

I have a handler for creating a comments. And I have a second handler for creating a tasks.

Both handlers have implemented the same interface

```
public interface IHandle<TCommand>
{
      void Handle(TCommand);
}
```

Now, I need to create a comment right after a task was successfuly created. But on the other hand I still need the comment handler as a standalone handler.

So I'm wondering what would be the best solution for reusing the comment handler.

My first thought was simply injecting the comment handler into the task handler and then just call the comment handler inside the task handler Handle method.

My infrastructure is a ASP.NET MVC application where I resolve the handler using my IoC container and then execute the handler. I'm not using any message bus.

Comment: Is the Comment part of your domain? Is Comment its own Aggregate Root or is it just a comment on the Task?

Comment: In that case you could send two Commands. One to create that Task and one to create the Comment. Given that you have set the Task Id in the Task command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a TaskCreatedEvent handler that sends a CreateComment command once the TaskCreatedEvent has occurred. This basically is what would be called a Saga and coordinates processes across aggregate boundaries.